# Python Pandas and NumPy.where behavior with mismatching numbers of rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, where-clause

I'm using Pandas 0.8.1 in all of the examples below, but I can confirm that the same examples work the same way for me when I use Pandas 0.11.

Solutions that rely on changing Pandas versions to a newer version aren't applicable for my current problem (although please feel free to add *comments* (not answers) about whether this is fixed in newer Pandas versions).

I have a sample Pandas DataFrame object

```
In [20]: dfrm
Out[20]:
          A         B         C     D
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN
8 -2.329704 -0.475419  1.473144    24
9  1.161275  0.918900 -1.077892    27
```

First, I'm a little confused about a type error that I'm seeing. If I try to use `numpy.where` to create some string labels of different subsets of a particular column, it looks like the string-nature of the label creates an error.

```
In [21]: np.where(dfrm['D'] > 12, 'L', 'S')
Out[21]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a40c5cd8713c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.where(dfrm['D'] > 12, 'L', 'S')

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
    236             self.start_displayhook()
    237             self.write_output_prompt()
--> 238             format_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
    239             self.write_format_data(format_dict)
    240             self.update_user_ns(result)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
    148             MIME type representation of the object.
    149         """
--> 150         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
    151
    152     def write_format_data(self, format_dict):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
    124                     continue
    125             try:
--> 126                 data = formatter(obj)
    127             except:
    128                 # FIXME: log the exception

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    445                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    446                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 447             printer.pretty(obj)
    448             printer.flush()
    449             return stream.getvalue()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    358                             if callable(meth):
    359                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)
--> 360             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    361         finally:
    362             self.end_group()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    478     if getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    479         # A user-provided repr.
--> 480         p.text(repr(obj))
    481         return
    482     p.begin_group(1, '<')

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __repr__(self)
    772             result = self._get_repr(print_header=True,
    773                                     length=len(self) > 50,
--> 774                                     name=True)
    775         else:
    776             result = '%s' % ndarray.__repr__(self)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _get_repr(self, name, print_header, length, na_rep, float_format)
    833                                         length=length, na_rep=na_rep,
    834                                         float_format=float_format)
--> 835         return formatter.to_string()
    836
    837     def __str__(self):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in to_string(self)
    109
    110         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 111         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    112
    113         maxlen = max(len(x) for x in fmt_index)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _get_formatted_values(self)
    100         return format_array(self.series.values, None,
    101                             float_format=self.float_format,
--> 102                             na_rep=self.na_rep)
    103
    104     def to_string(self):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
    460                         justify=justify)
    461
--> 462     return fmt_obj.get_result()
    463
    464

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in get_result(self)
    479             fmt_values = self._format_strings(use_unicode=True)
    480         else:
--> 481             fmt_values = self._format_strings(use_unicode=False)
    482
    483         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _format_strings(self, use_unicode)
    512         vals = self.values
    513
--> 514         is_float = lib.map_infer(vals, com.is_float) & notnull(vals)
    515         leading_space = is_float.any()
    516

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in notnull(obj)
    100     boolean ndarray or boolean
    101     '''
--> 102     res = isnull(obj)
    103     if np.isscalar(res):
    104         return not res

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in isnull(obj)
     58     from pandas.core.generic import PandasObject
     59     if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
---> 60         return _isnull_ndarraylike(obj)
     61     elif isinstance(obj, PandasObject):
     62         # TODO: optimize for DataFrame, etc.

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in _isnull_ndarraylike(obj)
     75         shape = values.shape
     76         result = np.empty(shape, dtype=bool)
---> 77         vec = lib.isnullobj(values.ravel())
     78         result[:] = vec.reshape(shape)
     79

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.isnullobj (pandas/src/tseries.c:5269)()

ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('s')
```

If I replace the strings 'L' and 'S' with integers like -1 and 1 it works OK, so that's a work around. But the stranger issue is what happens if I look at mixing the output of `np.where` with a DataFrame that has fewer rows.

```
In [22]: dfrm1 = dfrm.ix[0:7]

In [23]: dfrm1
Out[23]:
          A         B         C     D
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN

In [24]: dfrm
Out[24]:
          A         B         C     D
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN
8 -2.329704 -0.475419  1.473144    24
9  1.161275  0.918900 -1.077892    27
```

** Why does the following line work without error? **

```
In [25]: dfrm1['E'] = np.where(dfrm['D'] > 12, -1, 1)

In [26]: dfrm1
Out[26]:
          A         B         C     D  E
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0  1
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3  1
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6  1
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None  1
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12  1
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15 -1
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18 -1
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN  1
```

Even if I first save off the output from `np.where` (which will *not* have the right number of rows for the smaller DataFrame `dfrm1`), using the saved object works too.

```
In [28]: tmp = np.where(dfrm['D'] > 12, -1, 1)

In [29]: tmp
Out[29]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5   -1
6   -1
7    1
8   -1
9   -1
Name: D

In [30]: dfrm1['F'] = tmp

In [31]: dfrm1
Out[31]:
          A         B         C     D  E  F
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0  1  1
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3  1  1
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6  1  1
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None  1  1
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12  1  1
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15 -1 -1
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18 -1 -1
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN  1  1
```

I thought it might be due to Pandas somehow sharing metadata about Index objects and perhaps being allowed to truncate when inserting data if the data comes from an object that has the same index.

```
In [33]: tmp1 = tmp.reset_index(drop=True)

In [34]: dfrm1['G'] = tmp1

In [35]: dfrm1
Out[35]:
          A         B         C     D  E  F  G
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0  1  1  1
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3  1  1  1
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6  1  1  1
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None  1  1  1
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12  1  1  1
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15 -1 -1 -1
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18 -1 -1 -1
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN  1  1  1
```

But even after exploring the specific object IDs of the Index objects, there isn't a clear pattern.

```
In [36]: id(tmp.index)
Out[36]: 96118016

In [37]: id(tmp1.index)
Out[37]: 104735160

In [38]: id(dfrm.index)
Out[38]: 96118016

In [39]: id(dfrm1.index)
Out[39]: 104322304
```

Note that if I just try to assign a range of data of incorrect dimension, that fails:

```
In [40]: dfrm1['H'] = np.arange(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-987f4eb97131> in <module>()
----> 1 dfrm1['H'] = np.arange(10)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   1710         else:
   1711             # set column
-> 1712             self._set_item(key, value)
   1713
   1714     def _boolean_set(self, key, value):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   1749         ensure homogeneity.
   1750         """
-> 1751         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   1752         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   1753

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _sanitize_column(self, key, value)
   1778                     value = value.reindex(self.index).values
   1779             else:
-> 1780                 assert(len(value) == len(self.index))
   1781
   1782                 if not isinstance(value, np.ndarray):

AssertionError:

In [41]: dfrm1['H'] = np.arange(8)

In [42]: dfrm1
Out[42]:
          A         B         C     D  E  F  G  H
0  1.202034 -0.285256  0.392160     0  1  1  1  0
1  1.799628 -0.169389 -0.305984     3  1  1  1  1
2  1.262144 -1.165034 -1.780316     6  1  1  1  2
3 -0.355975  1.610605  1.298506  None  1  1  1  3
4 -0.139220  0.024292  0.132928    12  1  1  1  4
5  0.921821 -0.109189 -0.539100    15 -1 -1 -1  5
6  0.987901 -1.253987 -1.139684    18 -1 -1 -1  6
7  2.170929  0.520814 -0.139740   NaN  1  1  1  7
```

Why would the output of `np.where` be treated any differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is expected; you are assigning a series to a DataFrame column. it is aligned so shorter (or longer) is irrelevant. the index is matched up and those values are taken. the reason straight numpy array only works if the length is the same is simple; Alignment isn't possible so it must be the same length.

the id if an index is not relevant; only if it compares equal, eg i1.equals(i2)

try this whole exercise with labels that are not numbers or are offset (and not starting at 0 and you will see if alignment at work)

Comment: That seems like badly misleading default behavior and certainly not desired. For example, in the case where I reset the index, then the index (regardless of the left-hand-side DataFrame's index) is just a listing of 0 through N, not at all meant to be useful information for alignment (the whole point of a reset_index with drop=True). So the takeaway is that if you happen to use the same indices for the two DataFrames and one is a truncated version of the other (even if you didn't intend for them to be semantically seen as the "same" index) then it will accidentally work.

Comment: it's not misleading at all; in fact it's the primary reason for having an index in general; all operations align. if you don't wnt it then use numpy directly which doesn't align

Comment: It's the primary reason for using an alignment index, not a generic index, which are semantic concepts. I might want to access different rows by their number in a rectangular data array that has the potential to be aligned and has other labeling features, like column labels. But that doesn't mean that I want the row index to be treated *by default* as a unit for matching or aligning. There are a ton of uses for indices besides aligning, so it seems overly specific to me that Pandas will assume row indices are always intended for aligning.

Comment: Put another way, observation number 3 from DataFrame A might have nothing to do with observation 3 from DataFrame B except that they are both the third observation in their respective data containers. But after later reindexing by some other columns, they might have a meaningful relationship. Many operations are easier to perform prior to making the commitment to that reindex-by-some-columns step, and in the meantime I wouldn't want the DataFrame's to assume alignment by location within the datasets, especially for differently-shaped data.

Comment: then just use the ``.values`` after the ``np.where`` and use at your own risk. you are mixing concepts here. The purpose of pandas is to align by the index. There could be a non-alignment index I suppose, but then what's the point? If you don't care at all, then use straight numpy. Then when you do care about an index, put it in a frame.

Comment: I'm feeling a little frustrated by these comments, but I appreciate what you're saying. I disagree that Pandas has a "point" other than being a rectangular data container that can solve some problems. The "use" of an index depends on the application and the semantic meaning the user imparts to the index, it's not embedded just because it's a "Pandas index" -- that doesn't make it special. Converting things back and forth to NumPy would also be silly. Many many times in my day to day use of Pandas I encounter cases where I don't want to re-index by key columns until after some preprocessing.

Comment: Having said that, I suppose using `.values` is a good approach given the weird convention to disregard mismatching lengths whenever alignment on a subset of rows is possible.

Comment: I think you also might want to separate your work into separate frames that DO have meaning. Then merge/combine at a later step.

Comment: Sometimes that's a good idea, but it's not a restriction that the data container should impose on the programmer. Let the programmer decide when they want to enforce that. In my case, the DataFrames do have a relationship, and the "proper" way to do this is to first calculate the column that I want in the second DataFrame (the argument of `np.where`), then perform a `merge` or `join` based on other (non-index) columns. There are practical reasons not to set those columns as the index, and since I'm just relying on this as a data structure, it's no fun that it makes this assumption.

Comment: But given that `np.where` would be faster than a merge, it would be nice if I could trust that was just inserting values positionally, not by alignment, unless the index objects are actually the same object. But hey, that's just my opinion.

Comment: true....not pushing you to upgrade, but in (0.9 or 0.10) there is an alignable where, FYI. Yep sometimes its best to just keep the 'index' information as a column. Your problem is a bit 'unique' in that sometimes you don't want to align. I will think about this.

Comment: As I said above, you can simply use .values (and just make sure the length is correct, you are then responsible for padding to put the results where you want), and np.where does do this, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `ValueError` occurs because `where` will construct an `ndarray` of strings, but `isnullobj` takes an array of `object` `dtype`.
2. In version 0.8.1, the `where` assignment works because the right hand side of your expression (the `where` computation) returns a `Series` that can be reindexed to match the index of the smaller `DataFrame` on the left hand side.

Comment: For point 1, what's the preferred way around this? What if you want `np.where` to inspect a condition based on an `object` column, but then return a broadcasted scalar of some different type? The column that comes out of this must have the same type as the column within the condition?

Comment: No, it just can't handle the string dtypes. Cast them to `object`.

Comment: If I really really wanted the output to be of type `|S1`, say, does this mean I have to first cast to `object` to get it as a column, then re-assign the column with a call to `astype`? It seems really undesirable that I'd have to do this extra work instead of just getting that back directly from the broadcast performed by `np.where`.

Comment: `pandas` does not allow you to have string types in a frame, they will be converted to object so no matter how much you want it that won't work :)

Comment: The benefits of having `pandas` string methods and the flexibility of the object dtype outweigh whatever speed benefits are gained by using a `|Swhatever` typed array

Comment: Regardless, it seems silly to prevent users from controlling types at their own risk. I hesitate to say it's unPythonic since we're already talking about being in the midst of an indexed rectangular data structure, but in the spirit of not preventing people from doing difficult things if they want to, most Python types would not make a choice like this. I frustrates me when things like this are touted as features instead of looked at as interface bugs.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's a feature, but a trade-off. Unfortunately, this particular trade-off makes it feel like types are being enforced (and they are, to an extent). Of course, ideally you'd like performance *and* flexibility, but that's not always possible. That being said, there's plenty of room for performance improvements with `object` `Series` containing strings.